# Return value from a function based on which event handler is called

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq

I am publishing XML messages from WebAPI to a queue using RabbitMQ (.Net client library). If the published message is successfully persisted to the disk I need to send status code 200 if not code 400 should be returned. RabbitMQ client library provides two separate events to send ACK or NACK events indicating if the message was saved or not. So my publish function needs to wait for either of the two event handles to be called before I return http response.

How can I achieve this?

**Api Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SendSomething()
{
    ...
    bool success = _publisher.Publish(bytes);
    if(success) // Send status 200
    else // Send status 400
    ...
}
```

**Message Publish Code**

```
public bool Publish(byte[] data)
{
    ..
    channel.BasicAcks += OnAck;
    channel.BasicNacks += OnNack;
    channel.BasicPublish("", "test", null, data);
    ..
    // Depending on if OnAck or OnNack is called I need to return true or false
    return ??
}

private void OnNack(IModel model, BasicNackEventArgs args)
{
    ...
}

private void OnAck(IModel model, BasicAckEventArgs args)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read this right, you need to transform an asynchronous callback-based routine into a synchronous one. The naive answer would be to sleep the thread and wait for something to happen:

```
public bool Publish(byte[] data)
{
    //..
    bool? response = null;
    channel.BasicAcks += (model, args) => response = true;
    channel.BasicNacks += (model, args) => response = false;
    channel.BasicPublish("", "test", null, data);

    while (response == null)
        Thread.Sleep(300);

    return response.Value;
}
```

However, this means your response time will always be a multiple of 300ms, and you have the problem of implementing timeout logic the hard way. A better answer would probably be to use a [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This allows your callback to notify the blocked thread as soon as the response has been received, by "setting" the event:

```
public bool Publish(byte[] data)
{
    //..
    bool successful = false;
    var responseReceivedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    channel.BasicAcks += (model, args) => 
    { 
        successful = true; 
        responseReceivedEvent.Set(); 
    };
    channel.BasicNacks += (model, args) =>
    { 
        successful = false; 
        responseReceivedEvent.Set(); 
    };
    channel.BasicPublish("", "test", null, data);

    responseReceivedEvent.WaitOne();
    return successful;
}
```

In either case, you can (or should) implement some sort of timeout/retry logic, unless RabbitMQ does this for you. You can do this in the last example with the `WaitOne(int)` or `WaitOne(TimeSpan)` overloads of `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was already playing around with AutoResetEvent, but could not see the whole picture. And I like your use of lamda expressions. Thanks! :)